# Is the new functionality called "Microsoft Graph data connect" available for the Canada Central region?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-data-factory

I want to know if the functionality described in this link is available for Microsoft Canada Central region https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/build-2019-microsoft-graph-powers-the-microsoft-365-platform/.
How can I check if it is? I would like to use it in Datafactory.

Answer (score 0):

For me Microsoft Graph as the Azure AD are global services, so once their features are Generally Available (GA) it should be available everywhere.

For available regional services in Azure, you can check this page : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/

For data location of your Office 365 tenant : 
https://products.office.com/en-us/where-is-your-data-located